# What version of pygame does mu use?

Tags: pygame, thonny, mu

I recently found mu doesn't work due to an update for my operating system, and I was using it's built in pygame mode. I have now switched to a different editor (thonny) and was wondering which version/type it uses so I can use it there. The mu website doesn't say and I can't access the actual app to see.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygamd versions are fairly similar, i would recommend the newest available, it should be largely compatible.